# Laravel ElasticSearch: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm trying to add in a new index using the code below, using elasticsearch (elasticquent) 7.4.0 in laravel 6.5 (server side of elasticsearch is running on a dedicated server (docker) including Kibana GUI, the connection to this is working)

```
    <?php

// Article.php

namespace App;
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use ElasticquentTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'tags'];

    protected $mappingProperties = array(
        'title' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            "analyzer" => "standard",
        ],
        'body' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            "analyzer" => "standard",
        ],
        'tags' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            "analyzer" => "standard",
        ],
    );
}
```

But then I get the response:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [articles : {_source={enabled=true}, properties={title={analyzer=standard, type=text}, body={analyzer=standard, type=text}, tags={analyzer=standard, type=text}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [articles : {_source={enabled=true}, properties={title={analyzer=standard, type=text}, body={analyzer=standard, type=text}, tags={analyzer=standard, type=text}}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [articles : {_source={enabled=true}, properties={title={analyzer=standard, type=text}, body={analyzer=standard, type=text}, tags={analyzer=standard, type=text}}}]"}},"status":400}
```

I have been struggling with this for a while. I can't determine which parameter is unsupported. Any help is appreciated! Also, is there any way to get more detail from Kibana on the specific parameter is unsupported?

Comment: I think you're hitting this documented issue: https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/issues/222

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting [this issue](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/issues/222) (also documented [here](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/issues/214))

You simply need to add the following function in your model and it should work:

```
function getTypeName()
{
    return '_doc';
}
```

Comment: Now i get: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is s

Comment: Right, it seems some people [got around](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/issues/193#issuecomment-678837773) by removing the `setType` function. Please check it out as all related issues currently seem still open.

Comment: hmm this also doesn't affect it. thanks tho

Comment: To be honest, elasticquent seems to be way behind in terms of compatibility with ES. Last commit more than a year ago 

Comment: Thankt i am going to try elasticsearch